# Typeclass confusions when using `=>` operator?

Tags: haskell, syntax, typeclass, functional-dependencies

I have a basic typeclass:

```
class MyClass a where
  (-+) :: a -> a -> a

instance MyClass Int where
  e1 -+ e2 = e1 + e2 * 100

myFunction :: MyClass a => a -> a -> a
myFunction e1 e2 = e1 -+ e2
```

I understand how the above works.

However, I don't understand the use of the `=>` operator in this typeclass declaration:

```
class Monad m => MonadReader r m | m -> r where
```

Is this making MonadReader class related to the Monad class? Why is this used?

Comment: This is saying that `Monad m` must always hold when `MonadReader r m` holds. `Monad m` is a superclass of `MonadReader r m` (although I'm not sure the word _superclass_ was ever really meant to scale to multi-param type classes like `MonadReader`).

Comment: `Monad m =>` can be read as *"when m is a Monad"*, both in a function definition and in a class definition. In the latter case it does establish a relationship between Monad and MonadReader. Namely, every instance of `MonadReader r` is necessarily an instance of `Monad`. IOW it makes `MonadReader r` a *subclass* of `Monad` (if you can ever apply this notion to multiparameter type classes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
class Monad m => MonadReader r m | m -> r where
```

we have

1. The superclass constraint `Monad m`, which means that two given types `r` and `m` can be made instances of `MonadReader r m` if they not only implement the methods enumerated in `MonadReader`'s definition, but also the constraint `Monad m` holds, i.e. `m` is an instance of the `Monad` typeclass.
2. There is a functional dependency determining `r` from `m`, i.e. for any two `instance`s of `MonadReader r1 m1` and `MonadReader r2 m2`, if `m1 ~ m2` then `r1 ~ r2`.